# how to call a class function from jquery php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working with the plugin ParamQuery grid and to the data source need to get json data,
this what I want to do with $. getJson (...) {}, but I have a PHP class called data.php, which contains
a method called GetData other InsertData, DeleteData, (CRUD-using PDO), GetData returns the infromacion as json.
**The problem is how to call the function from jquery**?

the code I use is:

data.php

```
   <?php
   class Data {
   private $db = NULL;
   const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
   const DB_USER = "root";
   const DB_PASSWORD = "usbw";
   const DB_NAME = "musicstore";

   public function __construct() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . self::DB_NAME . ';host=' . self::DB_SERVER;
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->db;
   }

    public function getData() {

    $statement = $this->db->prepare("Select * from Customer");
    $statement->execute();

    if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo json_encode($statement);
    }

    return false;
     }
   }
 ?>
```

functionjquery.js

```
    $.getJSON('Data.php', function(data) {
var obj = {};
obj.width = 1000;
obj.height = 400;
obj.colModel = [{title: "Rank", width: 150, dataType: "integer"},
    {title: "Company", width: 200, dataType: "string"},
    {title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 200, dataType: "float", align: "right"},
    {title: "Profits ($ millions)", width: 200, dataType: "float", align: "right"}];
obj.dataModel = {data: data};
$("#grid_array").pqGrid(obj);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a page which constructs an instance of the `Data` class and then outputs the results of `getData()`

You shouldn't be `echo`ing from inside a function though. Change your `getData` method to something like the following:

```
public function getData() {
    $statement = $this->db->prepare("Select * from Customer");
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->rowcount() > 0 ? $statement->fetchAll() : NULL;
}
```

Then, create a new page let's call it `json_data.php` for transparency's sake:

```
require_once "data.php";
$dataObj = new Data();
echo json_encode($dataObj->getData());
```

Now change your `$.getJSON` call in jQuery to request the `json_data.php` page.

```
$.getJSON('json_data.php', function(data) { ... });
```

And that should work.

Comment: But we can instantiate a class in `data.php` file itself right?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can pass the parameter `data` along with the `$.getJSON` request to identify which method to be executed.

For Eg.

in **functionjquery.js**

```
$.getJSON('data.php', { method:'get' }, function(data) { ... });
```

in **data.php**

Change it as @Jason stated for best practice, and within that

```
if(isset($_GET['method'])){
    switch (($_GET['method'])) {
        case 'get':
            echo json_encode(getData());
            exit();

        //other cases go here

        default:
            break;
    }        
}
```

In this way no need to create additional pages for each method

Comment: proves how I work, but the proposed instruction is placed in the file header data.php??